describe-char renders the character, but not the buffer
I put some unicode text in a buffer and it looks like this:

But if I move to that box and run M-x describe-char I see it rendered correctly at the bottom, next to "decomposition". So, Emacs has the font. How do I get to render correctly in the normal buffer, and at the top of the describe-char info (2nd line)?
The character in this case is the KANGXI RADICAL BAMBOO: ⽵.
I'm on Windows 11. Emacs version: 29.2.


竹 (CJK IDEOGRAPH-7AF9) is a different character than ⽵ (KANGXI RADICAL BAMBOO). You apparently don’t have a font that supplies a glyph for the latter, but you do for the former. Install better fonts.

My system has the fonts. Other programs (eg, Notepad, Wordpad) display a string with that that character. Maybe there is a way to tell Emacs to use a certain font for certain Unicode code points, if there are no glyphs for them in its default face?

It already falls back to any other font on the system if it cannot find a glyph in your default font. You don't have a font with a glyph for the radical character, but your fonts do have a glyph for the ideograph character.

Try installing the Google Noto Serif family of fonts - when I do C-u C-x = on the ⽵ (KANGXI RADICAL BAMBOO)  (0x2f75), I get the following: display: by this font (glyph code):     ftcrhb:-GOOG-Noto Serif CJK JP-bold-normal-normal-*-22-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x738A) - note that the corresponding output in your question says: display: no font available which (I think) is an indication that no font that Emacs knows about contains a glyph for that character. BTW, please don't use images where a text display suffices.

I have Noto Sans SC (Simplified Chinese) from the Google fonts site. That has a glyph for the Unicode character, and yet emacs is not using it - it still says display: no font available. I'll try the Noto Serif Simplified Chinese too and report back if it's any different, but I don't see why it would use that, if not using the first. About the images - I'm asking about display, and in both cases if I paste the text it will display differently here in the browser than what is showing on the screen in Emacs. So they seem appropriate for this question. (?)

@db48x Here's why I think my font has the U+2F75 character. I open the "Character Map" app on Windows, select "Noto Sans SC", and scroll down in the list to 2F75. It shows the glyph. I can hover over it, and it shows that Unicode code point number. And this isn't the only font on my system that shows a glyph for that code point.

But Noto Sans SC and Noto Serif SC don’t sound like monospaced fonts. Your default font is monospaced, so it wants to fall back to a monospaced font. But if you think it is a bug then you can always use M-x report-emacs-bug to report it.
